# Is there some kind of deep relationship between substitution and recursion?

Tags: logic, soft-question, category-theory, recursion, universal-algebra

Define $\mathbb{N}$ as the initial object in the following category:

> **Objects.** Sets $X$ equipped with a function $S : X \rightarrow X$ and an element $0:X$.
>
> **Morphisms.** Functions that preserves $S$ and $0$.

In words: "$\mathbb{N}$ is defined to be the initial pointed monounary algebra."

This raises the question: "How are we to define addition?" There's at least two possible ways of doing so:

> **Approach 0. (Recursion.)** $+$ is the unique function $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that the following hold:
>
> $$a + S(b) = S(a)+b, \qquad a+0 = a$$

For example, lets show that $2+2=4$.

$$S(S(0))+ S(S(0)) = S(S(S(0)))+S(0) = S(S(S(S(0))))+0 = S(S(S(S(0))))$$

> **Approach 1. (Substitution.)** $+$ is the function $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ given as follows:
>
> $$a+b = [0 \leftarrow a](b)$$
>
> (Where $[0\leftarrow a]$ is the "substitution operator" that replaces each instance of $0$ with $a$.)

For example: $$S(S(0))+S(S(0)) = [0 \leftarrow S(S(0))]S(S(0)) = S(S(S(S(0))))$$

> **Question.** Is it more than just a coincidence that we can define $+$ in two different ways like this? In particular, is there some kind of deep relationship between substitution and recursion that I'm not seeing?

Answers from a categorial / universal algebraic viewpoint are especially welcome.

**Addendum.** In the comment's section, it was requested that the substition operator be defined precisely. Here's one way of doing this. By a monounary algebra, I mean a set $X$ equipped with a function $S : X \rightarrow X$. Then $\mathbb{N}$ can be viewed as the monounary algebra freely generated by $\{0\}$. So for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a unique homomorphism of monounary algebras $\varphi_n : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $\varphi_n(0) = n$. We can denote $\varphi_n$ by $[0 \leftarrow n]$.

Comment: You need to be more precise what you are talking about, because it is not true that syntactic substitution is enough to capture addition in first-order PA, because there are non-standard models of PA with elements that are not expressible syntactically in the language of PA, so it is meaningless to talk about syntactic substitution. The recursive definition on the other hand is part of the axioms of PA and so remain true in all models of PA.

Comment: @user21820, this has absolutely nothing to do with PA...

Comment: Then how do you **define** the substitution operator **precisely**?

Comment: @user21820, I've added a definition.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for adding that. In that case I think this phenomenon is peculiar to addition on natural numbers. In particular I think one can do this here because addition is commutative (besides being associative). $a + S(b) = a + (1+b) = (a+1) + b = (1+a) + b = S(a) + b$, so approach 0 works because of commutativity. Similarly approach 1 works because commutativity of applying iterates of $S$ guarantees the existence of such a homomorphism; namely $φ_a \circ S = S^a \circ S^1 = S^1 \circ S^a = S \circ φ_a$. So both seem to boil down to commutativity.

Comment: Does my latest comment make sense, or am I missing something about your question?

Comment: @user21820, the latest comment seems to make sense; you're saying the ability to define $+$ in two different ways is probably just a coincidence.

Comment: Yes, if I didn't miss any deeper reason it's a coincidence that seems to me just due to commutativity of $S$ and $S^a$. So this same phenomenon may show up elsewhere if this kind of commutativity is present but I see no other reason.

Answer (score 1):

We can construct the initial algebra $\mathbb{N}$ of the category you describe as the set of all terms built from a nullary constructor (operation symbol) $\mathsf{Z}$ and a unary constructor $\mathsf{S}$.  The initiality means that for any diagram of sets and functions $1\xrightarrow{z} X\xrightarrow{s} X$, there is a unique function $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to X$ such that

1. $f(\mathsf{Z}) = z$;
2. $f(\mathsf{S} (n)) = s(f(n))$, for any $n\colon\mathbb{N}$.

This is a special form of recursive definitions, called a catamorphism or a “right [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Folds_as_structural_transformations)” (in functional programming).  At the same time, we can see this as a form of substitution: if we read the equations as evaluation rules, from left to right, the first replaces each occurrence of $\mathsf{Z}$ by $z$ and the second replaces each occurrence of $\mathsf{S}$ by $s$, so that a term $\mathsf{S}(\mathsf{S}\cdots (\mathsf{S}(\mathsf{Z}))\cdots)$ evaluates to $s(s\cdots (s(z))\cdots)$.

This works for addition: $m + -$ is the unique function $f$ such that:

1. $f(\mathsf{Z}) = m$;
2. $f(\mathsf{S} (n)) = \mathsf{S} (f (n))$.

It replaces each occurrence of $\mathsf{Z}$ by $m$ and each occurrence of $\mathsf{S}$ by $\mathsf{S}$, so that $m + \mathsf{S}(\mathsf{S}\cdots (\mathsf{S}(\mathsf{Z}))\cdots)$ evaluates to $\mathsf{S}(\mathsf{S}\cdots (\mathsf{S}(m))\cdots)$.  This is the recursive definition of addition corresponding to your “substitutive” definition.

We can also put your recursive definition of addition into catamorphism form by defining $m + n$ as $f(n)(m)$ for the unique function $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to (\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N})$ such that:

1. $f(\mathsf{Z}) = \mathrm{id}$;
2. $f(\mathsf{S} (n)) = (f (n)) \circ \mathsf{S}$ [pointwise, this is $m + \mathsf{S} (n) = \mathsf{S} (m) + n$],

so that $- + \mathsf{S}(\mathsf{S}\cdots (\mathsf{S}(\mathsf{Z}))\cdots)$ evaluates to $(\cdots(id\circ\mathsf{S})\cdots \circ \mathsf{S})\circ \mathsf{S}$.

As another example, $m^{-}$ is the unique function $f$ such that:

1. $f(\mathsf{Z}) = 1$;
2. $f(\mathsf{S} (n)) = m \cdot f (n)$.

It replaces each occurrence of $\mathsf{Z}$ by $1$ and each occurrence of $\mathsf{S}$ by $m\cdot -$, so that $m^{\mathsf{S}(\mathsf{S}\cdots (\mathsf{S}(\mathsf{Z}))\cdots)}$ evaluates to $m\cdot(m\cdot\cdots (m\cdot 1)\cdots)$.

---

The relationship between recursion and substitution is perhaps clearer if we represents natural numbers by λ-terms, using [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding).  I will use a typed version, since it’s more readable and the parallel with the discussion above is more visible.  There are two kinds of λ-terms: application of a term $f$ of type $A\to B$ to a term $a\colon A$, noted $f\,a\colon B$, and λ-abstraction $(\lambda x\colon A. t)\colon A\to B$, where $t\colon B$ under the assumption that $x\colon A$.  There is one evaluation rule, β-reduction: $(\lambda x\colon A. t) a$ evaluates to $t \{x\mapsto a\}$ ($t$ in which $a$ is substituted for $x$).

The type of natural numbers can be defined as $\mathbb{N}\triangleq \forall X. (X\to X)\to (X \to X)$, i.e. the type of functions mapping a type $X$, a function $s\colon X\to X$ and an element $z\colon X$ to an element of type $X$ (this is the Böhm-Berarducci encoding of the inductive type of natural numbers).  Individual natural numbers can be defined using Church encoding (we will use $\Lambda X. t$ to represent functions on types, and $t\, [X]$ to represent type application):

- zero is $\Lambda X. \lambda s\colon X\to X. \lambda z\colon X. z$ (the function mapping $X$, $s$ and $z$ to $z$);
- one is $\Lambda X. \lambda s\colon X\to X. \lambda z\colon X. s\,z$;
- two is $\Lambda X. \lambda s\colon X\to X. \lambda z\colon X. s\,(s\,z)$;
- etc.

Now, if we are given a type $X'$, with $z'\colon X'$ and $s'\colon X'\to X'$, the corresponding catamorphism $\mathbb{N}\to X'$ is very easy to define: it’s just $\lambda n\colon\mathbb{N}. n\,[X']\,s'\,z'$ (i.e. $n$ applied to the catamorphism data, since $n$ is precisely a function taking such data and returning an element of $X'$).

To evaluate $n\,[X']\, s'\, z'$ for a specific $n$ of the form $\Lambda X. \lambda s\colon X\to X. \lambda z\colon X. s\,(s\, \cdots (s\,z)\cdots)$, we apply the β-reduction rule for each application, i.e. we substitute $s'$ for $s$ and $z'$ for $z$, obtaining $s'\,(s'\, \cdots (s'\,z')\cdots)$.

---

This can be generalised to other kinds of algebras (lists, various kinds of trees).

Comment: In the Böhm-Berarducci definition of $\mathbb{N}$, I'm not sure what the $\forall$ means. Are you basically saying: $$\mathbb{N} = \prod_{X:\mathbf{Set}} (X \rightarrow X) \rightarrow (X \rightarrow X)$$? Or perhaps $$\mathbb{N} = \lim_{X:\mathbf{Set}} (X \rightarrow X) \rightarrow (X \rightarrow X)$$? If the latter, how are we to regard $(X \rightarrow X) \rightarrow (X \rightarrow X)$ as a functor?

Comment: The only “functions” mapping a type to a term we can define in System F are uniform over types (we can do no case analysis on types), so that, if we can interpret them in terms of classical sets, it should be as natural (or dinatural in case of mixed variance) transformations.  

The type of natural numbers defined above can be interpreted as the end $$\int_X (X \to X) \to (X\to X)$$ or $$\int_X ((X\to X)\times X)\to X$$ in the category of sets.  (But, in general, it is not possible to interpret System F types as classical sets.)